# AngularJS loading progress bar

Tags: angularjs

When using AngularJS and doing a redirect using `$location.path('/path')` the new page takes a while to load, especially on mobile.

Is there a way to add a progress bar for loading? Maybe something like YouTube has?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For a progress bar as YouTube has, you can take a look at [ngprogress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/). Then just after the configuration of your app (for example), you can [intercept route's events](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route).

And do something like:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, ngProgress) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    ngProgress.start();
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    ngProgress.complete();
  });
  // Do the same with $routeChangeError
});
```

Comment: You forgot to inject ngProgress: 
.run(function($rootScope, ngProgress)

Comment: N.b. this answer no longer applies. Look at @rsobon 's answer at the bottom of this page for an up to date implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Since @Luc's anwser [ngProgress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/) changed a bit, and now you can only inject `ngProgressFactory`, that has to be used to create ngProgress instance. Also contrary to @Ketan Patil's answer you should only instantiate ngProgress **once**:

```
angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngProgress']).run(function ($rootScope, ngProgressFactory) { 

    // first create instance when app starts
    $rootScope.progressbar = ngProgressFactory.createInstance();

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
        $rootScope.progressbar.start();
    });

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {
        $rootScope.progressbar.complete();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is the next route that takes time to load e.g. making ajax call before the controller is run (resolve config on route) then make use of $route service's $routeChangeStart, $routeChangeSuccess and $routeChangeError events.

register a top level controller (outside ng-view) that listens to these events and manages a boolean variable in its $scope.

use this variable with ng-show to overlay a "loading, please wait" div.

if the next route loads fast (i.e. its controller runs quickly) but data that are requested by the controller take a long to load then, i'm afraid, you have to manage the visibility state of spinners in your controller and view.

something like:

```
$scope.data = null;
$http.get("/whatever").success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});

<div ng-show="data !== null">...</div>
<div ng-show="data === null" class="spinner"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use angular-loading-bar

Standalone demo here ..
https://github.com/danday74/angular-loading-bar-standalone-demo

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working solution which I am using in my application. [ngProgress](https://github.com/victorbjelkholm/ngprogress) is the best library out there for showing load-bars when changing urls.

Remember to inject the ngProgressFactory instead of ngProgress, as opposed to Luc's solution.

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).run(function ($rootScope, ngProgressFactory) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
        $rootScope.progressbar = ngProgressFactory.createInstance();
        $rootScope.progressbar.start();

    });

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {
        $rootScope.progressbar.complete();
    });
});
```

**Update Nov-2015** - After analyzing this approach with chrome timings, I have observed that this would not be the correct way for adding a loading bar. Sure, the loading bar will be visible to visitors,but it will not be in sync with actual page load timings.