# The simpliest way to do an AngularJS progress bar asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I have this piece of code :

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "processing",
    data: $scope.jsonResult,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $window.location.href = '/MatrixIIS';
}, function errorCallback(response) {});
```

My main issue is that when I reload the page I have too much data to fetch so my user interface get blocked. So what i'd like to do is to post data and when I reload the page use another http request by using get method and during the uploading display a progress bar.

How can I achieve this in the simplest way?

Comment: [angular-material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressLinear) has a nice progress bar.  Might be worth looking at. It's probably quite a large library for you to download just for a progress bar though.

Comment: ok thanks i am going to check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS loading progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779917/angularjs-loading-progress-bar)