# how do i add a progress bar in client side in html

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using Angular directive to file upload, but I need to add a progress bar to html view to weather image is uploaded to form or not.

```
geniusPos.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;`

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    `modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);`
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144180/angularjs-loading-screen-on-ajax-request) might helps you!!

Comment: Just try angular-loader... It would be a progress bar for all the http requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS loading progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779917/angularjs-loading-progress-bar)